# How to replace a character in a string in Erlang?

Tags: replace, erlang, character

I want to check if a string contains a specific character ("`*`") and if so, I want to replace it with another character ("`%`").

Like this: `String = "John*"`

Changes to: `String = "John%"`

Thank you

Comment: Elang or Erlang? If you ask for erlang : result = binary:replace("John*", "*", "%", [global]).

Comment: The `binary` module uses binaries for its function args, so those need to be binaries (e.g., `<<"John*">>`).

Comment: Erlang, I meant Erlang. Thank you both.

Comment: `string:replace("John*", "*", "%").`?

Answer (score 3):

Straightforward:

```
-module(replace).

-export([replace/3]).

replace([], _, _) -> [];
replace([H|T], P, R) ->
    [ if H =:= P -> R;
         true -> H
      end | replace(T, P, R)].
```

Usage:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(replace).
{ok,replace}
2> replace:replace("John*", $*, $%).
"John%"
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```erlang
1> io:format(string:replace("John*", "*", "%")).
John%ok
```

You can use [string:replace/3](https://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#replace-3).